# Django @login_required views for JSON data API's used from iPad/iPhone/Android?

Tags: iphone, android, django, ipad, asihttprequest

Django `@login_required` views for JSON data API's used from iPad/iPhone/Android?

In my Django webserver, I have built JSON data API's that I want to access from mobile devices: iPad/iPhone/Android.  I'm using the iPad/iPhone ASIHttp Library.  How do I login users from an iPad/iPhone so my data API's can use the @login_required decorator?

Answer (score 0):

Just as ordinary web applications did 
pass the username and password to the  auth api
then the login  will be evaluated and added into session, then you can finish the login process.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  How do you format a JSON username/password to match the Auth API?